# Is it possible to change cascade type dynamically in JPA/Hibernate?

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

Consider the following code:

```
@Entity
public class User {
    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "USER_ID")
    private List<UserRole> roles;

}
```

According to the code above User.roles will be loaded lazily. However, we can change this behavior using fetchgraph, something like this:

```
EntityGraph<User> graph = entityManager.createEntityGraph(User.class);
graph.addSubgraph("roles");
typedQuery.setHint("javax.persistence.fetchgraph", graph);
List<User> entities = typedQuery.getResultList();//roles will be eagerly loaded
```

Is is possible to make JPA provider/Hibernate create and update User with roles field when @OneToMany.cascade = null? By other words, I want to add cascade = CascadeType.ALL dynamically to have a full and dynamic control over entity tree for all create/update/delete operations.

Comment: No, you can not change `insertable = false, updatable = false` dynamically. Could you please explain why you need it?

Comment: If you want to update field then it means the field is updatable, so it does not make sense to set updatable=false. If you want to change only some fields during update, you can write your own JPQL query for example: "update Entity e set e.boolField = false where e.boolField = true"

Comment: The question is quite confusing. what does `insertable`/`updatable` have to do with entity graphs?

Comment: @crizzis You are right. I was wrong. I corrected my mistake and  edited the question.

Comment: It is still confusing as cascades have nothing to do with entity graphs and fetch types.